# Laravel Auth count user login

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I installed Laravel with the Laravel/Auth. 
How can i count how often a user logged in his account? 
I tried to find the updated_at function to add a increment command to push up the count.

Comment: after login in `AuthenticatesUsers`  Trait in `Login` method you can add code to calculate user login count and store it in database.

Comment: You want to count the logins or to see how often he loges in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use events to accomplish it. More information about events can be found on [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/events)

You should add a new property `loginCount` to the `User` model and its correspondent in db. Make sure that on creation the `loginCount` field has the default value set to `0`.

To increment it when user is logging in you can create a listener which listen on `auth.login` event:

1. Create the `UserEventListener` class in `app\Listeners`

   ```
   namespace App\Listeners;

   use App\User;

   class UserEventListener
   {
       /**
        * Handle user login events.
        * 
        * @param User $user
        * @param bool $remember
        */
       public function onUserLogin(User $user, $remember)
       {
           $user->loginCount++;
           $user->save();
       }

       /**
        * Register the listeners for the subscriber.
        *
        * @param  Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher  $events
        */
       public function subscribe($events)
       {
           $events->listen(
               'auth.login',
               'App\Listeners\UserEventListener@onUserLogin'
           );
       }
   }
   ```
2. Subscribe the `UserEventListener` to the `EventServiceProvider`

   ```
   namespace App\Providers;

   use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher as DispatcherContract;
   use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

   class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
   {
       /**
        * The event listener mappings for the application.
        *
        * @var array
        */
       protected $listen = [
           'App\Events\SomeEvent' => [
               'App\Listeners\EventListener',
           ],
       ];

       /**
        * The subscriber classes to register.
        *
        * @var array
        */
       protected $subscribe = [
           'App\Listeners\UserEventListener',
       ];

       /**
        * Register any other events for your application.
        *
        * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher  $events
        * @return void
        */
       public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
       {
           parent::boot($events);
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a new field into your users table. After this take a look and override the `postLogin` function in your controller. More information about this function can be found here `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers`.