# how to change the value of a column in laravel on logout

Tags: php, laravel-5

i have a column called active_user to show when a user is online(1). When i log a user in i set the active_user column to 1  but when i log the user out and check  active_user it still shows online(1). what i want is that when i click the logout button the aactive_user column will change to offline(0) and also update it to the database. my login is below.

```
 public function postSignIn(Request $request) {

    $this->validate($request, [

        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'

    ]);

   if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password']])) {
       $user=User::whereRaw('email=?',[Input::get('email')])->first();

       //this is where i set the active_user to 1
       $user->active_user=1;
       $user->save();

       if($user!=null){
           switch($user->role_id){
               case 1:
                   if($user->status==0){
                       session()->flash('flash_message_error', ' Your Account has been  deactivated. Contact the administrator');
                       return Redirect::to('admin/login');
                   }
                   return redirect()->route("index");
               break;
```

then below is my logout function

```
public function LogOut($id) {
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->active_user=1;
    $user->save();
    Auth::logout();

    return redirect('admin/login');
}
```

in the logout function i want to change the active_user back to offline(0) but i keep getting an error "Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\AdminController::LogOut()"

Comment: You can use login/logout events.. Take a look at this accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36767556/laravel-auth-count-user-login/36767937#36767937

Comment: what am tryning to do is to update the active_user back to Offline(0) when i clcik a logout button

Answer (score 1):

Your route logout is now expecting an `id` attribute passed to it. This seems wrong to me as it is the authenticated user that you want to apply this logic to, having to pass their id to logout is unnecessary. For example if your logged in user has an id of 1, to logout with your code they would need to go to a url such as:

```
http://myapp.app/logout/1
```

Instead, use the Auth implementation to modify the user.

```
// Remove requirement for ID as a parameter
public function LogOut() {
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->active_user=1;
    $user->save();
    Auth::logout();

    return redirect('admin/login');
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @DavidBarker i think that was my problem because my route was expecting an `id`. It is working now :). I appreciate